# json_extract a data set that appears in the field multiple times

Tags: arrays, json, mariadb, extract

So I am working on a game server and I have a player inventory that stores as a json field. I am trying to create a query that specifically pulls two of the data sets in the field but those data sets repeat. For example two of the data sets are going to be name: and amount: but the same field will use these data sets as many times as there are items in the inventory table.

So example here I call on the two data sets on a specific vehicle trunk identified by its plate in the database. What I get back are Null Null.

`SELECT json_extract(items, '$."amount"') AS amount, json_extract(items, '$."name"') AS name FROM trunkitems WHERE plate='6DV689SW';`

What I need it to do its return an expanding table for just those two data points.

Comment: Some questions: can you show an example of the JSON stored, and an example of the result you'd like to see? It's not clear what you mean by 'expanding table'. For instance, SQL can produce multiple rows, but it can't output extra columns depending on the data it reads. The columns are fixed in the select-list when you prepare the query.

Comment: Also you should run `SELECT VERSION();` on your database instance, and report what that says. You tagged both MariaDB and MySQL, but these are different products with different implementation for JSON functions. Please be clear about which brand and version you are using.

Comment: Sure, @BillKarwin the version running is 10.3.31-MariaDB

Comment: Here is a sample of the messy inventory JSON field. The only real information that matters is listing out the names of items and their amounts, which is why I only aim to call those two data sets. 

`[{"type":"item","slot":1,"label":"Bag of Ecstasy","useable":true,"unique":false,"name":"xtcbaggy","amount":2,"info":"","weight":0,"image":"xtc_baggy.png"},null,null,{"type":"item","slot":4,"label":"Document","useable":true,"unique":true,"name":"printerdocument","amount":1,"info":{"url":"https://i.imgur.com/GBOPk9T.png"},"weight":500,"image":"printerdocument.png"}]`

Answer (score 0):

The proper solution is to use [JSON_TABLE()](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_table/), but this function is not implemented in MariaDB until version 10.6. You said you are currently using MariaDB 10.3, so you'll have to upgrade to use this solution.

```
SELECT j.amount, j.name
FROM trunkitems
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(items, '$[*]' COLUMNS(
  amount INT PATH '$.amount',
  name VARCHAR(20) PATH '$.name'
)) AS j
WHERE j.name IS NOT NULL;
```

[Dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3HoMMxv2)

If you can't upgrade, then I recommend you store data in normal rows and columns, and not use JSON.

In fact, I usually recommend to avoid using JSON in MySQL or MariaDB in all cases. It just makes queries harder to write and maintain and optimize, and makes data take more storage space.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback, thank you